# echo json for more values from std object

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I have below code which check table whether value is NULL or not NULL and then echo message to view to tell user that value already exist,

In this code, multiselect input is taken and then check in mysql database for that selected id, if that id have value then code will send error message to user, and if value is NULL, then will proceed for further actions like add.

```
foreach($this->input->post('sla_department') as $department_id)
        {
            $departmentslacheck = $this->model_admin->checkdepartmentsla($department_id);

            if($departmentslacheck->sla_id !==  NULL)
            {
                echo json_encode(array('cival'=>0, 'val_message' => 'SLA already assigned to '.$departmentslacheck->department_name));

            }                   
        }
```

My problem is that when user select 2 or more values in HTML view and both have value in database table(means not NULL), then it send 2 JSON which is not expected by view, so i can not see error message,

With this i am getting JSON as below,

```
0: {cival: 0, val_message: "SLA already assigned to X"}
1: {cival: 0, val_message: "SLA already assigned to Y"}
```

How can i echo...

```
cival'=>0, 'val_message' => 'SLA already assigned to X , Y.
```

Where X and Y are database department_name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not echo the JSON straight away on a condition but compile the final result and then send it.

```
$result = [];
foreach($this->input->post('sla_department') as $department_id)
{
        $departmentslacheck = $this->model_admin->checkdepartmentsla($department_id);

        if($departmentslacheck->sla_id !==  NULL)
        {
            $result[] = $departmentslacheck->department_name;

        }                   
}

if (count($result) > 0)
{
    echo json_encode(array('cival'=>0, 'val_message' => 'SLA already assigned to '.implode(', ', $result)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an array before beginning the foreach loop,
push the array insde de loop to this array and echo a unique
json_encode of the main array:

```
 $result = array();
foreach($this->input->post('sla_department') as $department_id)
    {
        $departmentslacheck = $this->model_admin->checkdepartmentsla($department_id);

        if($departmentslacheck->sla_id !==  NULL)
        {
           $result[]=array('cival'=>0, 'val_message' => 'SLA already assigned to '.$departmentslacheck->department_name);

        }                   
    }
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: This will not produce the expected result though.